# Copy all PDFs within a listing of directories

Tags: grep, find

I am trying to copy all PDFs within a listing of directories to my temp directory. I have this command to get a listing applicable directories:

```
dirname $(grep -r <my search criteria> /c01/app/*sup) | sort -u
```

This searches through all `.sup` files for my search criteria. In those directories are PDFs I want to copy out.

EDIT: When running an updated command:

`dirname $(grep -r <my search criteria> /c01/app/09/*/*/*/*/*/system/output/*sup)) | sort -u | xargs -I {} cp -- {}/*pdf .`

I'm getting this error:
`cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ba/016/500/000/082/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory`

More output:

```
[user@server payment]$ dirname $(grep -r <my search> /c01/app/09/*/*/*/*/*/system/output/*sup) | sort -u | xargs -I {} cp -- {}/*pdf .

cp: cannot stat ‘./*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/026/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/030/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/033/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/086/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/0a7/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/112/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/191/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/030/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/033/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/036/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/03b/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/043/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/04b/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/04e/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/087/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/08d/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/096/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/09a/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/0a0/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/0a3/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/185/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/1c1/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/1c4/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/af/016/500/000/007/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/af/016/500/000/00a/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/af/016/500/000/00d/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/af/016/500/000/011/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/af/016/500/000/01c/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/af/016/500/000/01f/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/af/016/500/000/02a/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/af/016/500/000/042/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/af/016/500/000/08b/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b2/016/500/000/006/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b2/016/500/000/00b/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b2/016/500/000/018/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b2/016/500/000/024/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b2/016/500/000/026/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b2/016/500/000/02e/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b2/016/500/000/037/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b3/016/500/000/007/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b3/016/500/000/00a/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b3/016/500/000/00e/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b3/016/500/000/012/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b3/016/500/000/017/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b3/016/500/000/021/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b3/016/500/000/08d/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b3/016/500/000/15e/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b4/016/500/000/016/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b4/016/500/000/018/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b4/016/500/000/061/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b4/016/500/000/076/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b4/016/500/000/086/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b4/016/500/000/088/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b4/016/500/000/0df/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b5/016/500/000/00a/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b5/016/500/000/032/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b5/016/500/000/05b/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b5/016/500/000/066/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b9/016/500/000/004/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b9/016/500/000/014/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b9/016/500/000/01a/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b9/016/500/000/02e/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b9/016/500/000/03b/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b9/016/500/000/081/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b9/016/500/000/08b/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b9/016/500/000/08e/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b9/016/500/000/091/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/09/b9/016/500/000/098/system/output/*pdf’: No such file or directory
```

Output from your suggested command:

```
[user@server payment]$ dirname $(grep <my search> /c01/app/09/*/*/*/*/*/system/output/*sup) | sort -u | head
.
/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/026/system/output
/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/086/system/output
/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/0a7/system/output
/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/112/system/output
/c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/191/system/output
/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/030/system/output
/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/033/system/output
/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/036/system/output
/c01/app/09/ae/016/500/000/03b/system/output
```

Comment: But what is the output of the command? What is it that you are passing to xargs? We need to see the output of something like `dirname $(grep -r <my search criteria> /c01/app/09/*/*/*/*/*/system/output/*sup)) | sort -u | head` (also, you have an extra `)` there, I assume that's a typo).

Comment: Also, why are you using `grep -r` if you are giving a list of files?

Comment: @terdon updated the question with your suggested output, and pulled the `)`. That was erroneous.

Comment: And are there any PDFs in those directories? What is the output of `ls /c01/app/09/ad/016/500/000/026/system/output/*pdf`? Are you getting errors for all directories or only for those with no files?

Comment: Never mind. I'm an idiot and forgot that xargs doesn't call a shell so it can't handle shell globs. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shell loop:

```
dirname $(grep -r <my search criteria> /c01/app/*sup) | 
    sort -u |
        while IFS= read -r dir; do
            cp -- "$dir"/*pdf /path/to/target/dir
        done
```

You can also do it with `xargs`, but because `xargs` doesn't call a shell and instead invokes whatever utilities you tell it to directly, it will not expand `*pdf` to the list of files. This means you would need to call it with a shell explicitly:

```
    dirname $(grep -r <my search criteria> /c01/app/*sup) | 
        sort -u |
            xargs -I {} sh -c "cp -- {}/*pdf /path/to/target/dir"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am getting an error:

`cp: cannot stat ‘/c01/app/*pdf’: No such file or directory`

However, when I run the command separately, it runs just fine.

Comment: @etm124 please edit your question and i) show us the actual output of the command, at least part of it, and ii) show the _specific_ command from my answer you ran that gives you the error.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @etm124 I'm sorry, I should have tested the `xargs` one. You're absolutely right, it looks like it doesn't handle shell globs, presumably because it doesn't call a shell, just th. Just use the shell loop approach that one should work. Alternatively, you can call `sh` from `xargs` (see updated answer).